# SQL query from the Heroku database

Tags: sql, shell, heroku, command

I want to see the table from the database.
What could be the reason I got this table from the database??
(I wrote "select * from students")
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeUIA.jpg)

I tried closing and opening the system.
Is there another way to hunt down the Heroku database??

Thank you for the help.